# How to use sub-commands along with optional positional arguments in argparse

Tags: python, argparse, subparsers

Below scripts prints an output as well as opens a webpage based on command line arguments.

```
#main.py

import os, numpy
import argparse
import webbrowser

new=2

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
    parser.add_argument('-i','--input',type=str, help='Choose input')
    parser.add_argument('-d','--display',dest='disp',type=str, help='Opens a webpage', default=None)

    args = parser.parse_args()
 
    if args.input == 'infile':
        print('This is input file')

    if args.disp == 'openbrowser':
        url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
        webbrowser.open(url,new=new,autoraise=True)
     
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

If I use the following command:

```
python3 main.py --input infile --display openbrowser
```

The desired output is attained. But, I would like `--display` (ideally without any `str`) to be parsed along with `--input` as a sub-command and not as a separate optional flag argument `-d`. The flag `-display` is only used if `--input` is used as the primary flag, and even `--display` should be optional in itself and shouldn't be obligatory.

So I would like the command line arguments to look like:

```
python3 main.py --input infile --display
```

This prints `This is input file` and opens webpage in the browser. and

```
python3 main.py --input infile
```

This prints the output `This is input file` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `action='store_true'` property on the argument specification.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action

```py
parser.add_argument('-d', '--display', dest='disp',
                    action='store_true', help='Opens a webpage')
```

```py
#main.py

import os, numpy
import argparse
import webbrowser

new=2

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-i','--input',type=str, help='Choose input')
    parser.add_argument('-d','--display',dest='disp', action='store_true', help='Opens a webpage')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.input == 'infile':
        print('This is input file')

    if args.disp:
        url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
        webbrowser.open(url,new=new,autoraise=True)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: thanks, although this answer works I was thinking if there is a possibility to do the task via using `sub-parsers` where `-d` is dependent on `--input`.

Answer (score 1):

This should be exactly what you are looking for.

In order to add subcommands you use the `ArgumentParser.add_subparsers` method which requires no parameters and returns an object that can create as many subcommands as you would like.

```
import os, numpy
import argparse
import webbrowser

new=2

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 

    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
    input_parser = subparsers.add_parser("input")
    input_parser.add_argument('filename', help='path to file')
    args = parser.parse_args()
        input_parser.add_argument(
        '-d',
        '--display',
        dest='disp', 
        action='stor_true',  
        help='Opens a webpage'
     )

    if 'filename' in args:
        print('This is input file')
    if args.disp:
        url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
        webbrowser.open(url,new=new,autoraise=True)
     
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @I dont think this works with `python3 main.py --input filename --display`. Also I would like --input to be optional rather than positional argument

Comment: @newstudent You said you wanted input to be a subcommand  subcommands dont have prefix characters

Comment: I said I wanted --display to be the sub-command of --input, I've did write the command line arguments in my post

Comment: @newstudent You have a misunderstanding of how command line options work.  anything that starts with the prefix character `-` is an option flag.  Option flags don't have subcommands,   but  subcommands can have option flags.

Comment: @newstudent  I edited my answer... It now should operate the way you want, other than input doesn't have the prefix character also iwohlhart answer is also very similar